# Solving optimization problem restricted to non-convex subset

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization

I have two continuous random variables that have pdfs with respect to the Lebesgue measure $p_{-1}(x), p_1(x)$.
Let $m(x) := \frac{p_{-1}(x)+p_1(x)}{2}$ be a mixture of these two distributions.
Let $B(x) := \frac{p_1(x)-p_{-1}(x)}{p_1(x)+p_{-1}(x)}$ be such that

- $B(x) = 1$ if $p_1(x)>0=p_{-1}(x)$, and
- $B(x) = -1$ if $p_{-1}(x)>0=p_1(x)$.

There are probably other functions satisfying these properties — $B(x)$ comes up when studying the Le Cam metric though.

Let $\lVert f\rVert = \sqrt{\mathbb{E}_m[|f(x)|^2]}$ be the norm on $L^2(m)$, and let $\langle f,g\rangle = \mathbb{E}_m[f\cdot g]$ be the corresponding inner product.
Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of all functions $f\in L^2(m)$ such that $f : \mathbb{R}\to[-1,1]$, and let $\mathcal{F}_d$ be the set of all functions $f\in L^2(m)$ such that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\{-1,0,1\}$.

Anyway, I am interested in solving (or establishing strong bounds on) the quantity

$$\delta_{\mathcal{F}_d}(p_{-1}, p_1) = \sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}_d} \Big\langle \frac{f}{\lVert f\rVert}, B\Big\rangle.$$

It is not too hard to show that the related quantity $\delta_{\mathcal{F}}(p_{-1}, p_1) = \sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}} \langle \frac{f}{\lVert f\rVert}, B\rangle$ is exactly equal to the Le Cam metric between $p_{-1}$ and $p_1$ (which may be written many ways, for example $\lVert B^2\rVert$).
One can also show that

$$\delta_{\mathcal{F}_d}(p_{-1}, p_1) = \sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}} \Big\langle \frac{f}{\sqrt{\mathbb{E}_m[|f|}}, B\Big\rangle,$$

though this other quantity seems to be less natural to examine, so I will omit it in the rest of this post. So far I am able to get absolute bounds of the form

$$\delta_{\mathcal{F}_d}(p_{-1}, p_1) \leq \delta_{\mathcal{F}}(p_{-1}, p_1) \leq \delta_{\mathcal{F}_d}(p_{-1}, p_1)^{3/4},$$

as well as many bounds that depend on some properties of $p_{-1}$ and $p_1$.

Of course, there are some reasons to think the optimization problem over $\mathcal{F}_d$ may be inherently different (it seems that $\mathcal{F}$ is convex, and $\mathcal{F}_d$ is non-convex). Still, given that for most distributions that I care about, for example

1. $p_{-1}$, $p_1$ uniform over different sets,
2. $p_{-1}, p_1$ concentrated on a set $S$ of small size $|S|$$

I am able to improve the above result to

\begin{equation}
\forall \epsilon > 0 : \delta_{\mathcal{F}_d}(p_{-1}, p_1) \leq \delta_{\mathcal{F}}(p_{-1}, p_1) \leq C\delta_{\mathcal{F}_d}(p_{-1}, p_1)^{1-\epsilon},
\end{equation}
where $C_\epsilon$ is a constant dependent only on $\epsilon$ and $|S|$.

Is there a general literature on optimizing over sets of the form $\mathcal{F}_d$? It seems to be non-convex, so I don't know if things should still be reasonable or not.